# Android "Polling" Bluetooth vs Low Energy

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, polling

My client is building an application using a Bluetooth Low Energy dongle.  This unit takes continuous measurements.  They originally went with the BLE for energy purposes and power saving.  Since this unit will run for about 8 hours at a time while recording data, they will need it to operate the full 8 hours.

They want me to setup their android app to Poll the device on 4 different channels at a frequency of up to 250/sec.  To me that defeats the Low Energy aspect.  I am pretty sure that BLE was designed with notifications in mind which should send data to an app onChange instead of the app asking the device for data at a given frequency.

At the moment I have the App setup with device notifications.  That means that the GattServer is sending data and then the app is only receiving notifications of data change.  The problem with that is  that there are 2 channels for a sensor which require an amount of data at a rate of 250/sec.  Even if there is no change.

The server may or may not send at that rate.  For one channel I get about 25 reads er sec and for the other channel I get maybe 4 reads per second.  Since this is all setup with Notifications which only notify onChange I suspect that the app is doing exactly what it is designed to do. So since there are not enough data points, we are thinking of switching those two channels to polling instead.

Does this make sense to you and doesn't this defeat the Low Energy or even the entire design of a Low Energy chip design?

Answer (score 1):

`250/sec = 1 packet per 4ms`.

BLE's smallest connection interval is `7.5ms`. All data exchanged between master and slave must be done within a connection interval. Even though multiple packets can be sent back and forth within a single connection interval, I don't know how you are going to make Android squeeze multiple messages into one connection interval. In that way, you cannot make sure the 250 polls are equally spaced in time.

I think Android simply wouldn't let you send messages at that frequency. Send networking packets is usually a blocking operation. So your app will be blocked by the operating system when tx is busy. In the end, what you might get is simply tens of messages per second.

Comment: thank you.  That is what I was thinking and actually what I am experiencing. Thanks for the second eyes.

Comment: @RootWannaBe I forgot to mention that if you could touch the BLE periperhal's firmware, you could squeeze multiple samples into one frame. Say a sample takes up two bytes, you can bundle 10 samples (20 bytes, which is the maximum data payload of BLE) and send them all in one go.